# Small VB.NET application detected by Antivirus SONAR.Heuristic

Tags: vb.net, antivirus

I have written a very small application that basically looks into a text file and copies files to various locations on the computer based on path listings from the file.  Nothing major and nothing too complex at all.

However, when running this application on client computers, I am finding that SEP (Symantec End Point) is picking this application up as malicious (SONAR.Heuristic) and placing the file under quarantine.

The only thing I can think of which may have caused this is that I have compiled my application to run with highest privileges, but I can't see how that could be an issue.

Is there something else I can look for that may be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: Does your application make use of MailMessage Class? Sometimes this gets falsely detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes when apps write to certain locations that malware often write to, the AV will flag the app. I have found that this happens frequently with writes to the registry for startup.
You can try writing the files to a different location.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am in fact writing to the Program Files directory which could be causing the issue.  However, I have no choice but to write these files here.  I need to update the files that are currently in this directory with new updated ones.